# Why CSS path does not work for Jsoup.connect?

Tags: jsoup

I'm trying to extract data from a website using their css path with Jsoup's select method.

The data is returned when the html is a local file and I use Jsoup.parse().

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
String id = doc.select("#content > div.container-fluid > div > div:nth-child(2) > h2 > strong").text();
```

The data is not returned when the html is obtained using Jsoup.connect().get()

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
String id = doc.select("#content > div.container-fluid > div > div:nth-child(2) > h2 > strong").text();
```

The input file and url has the same html.

Comment: Do you mean input file and url has the same String value? Because input file should be a String `html` value, whereas url should be the website link

Comment: Are you really sure the input file and the contents of the website are the same? did you check? How? Jsoup may have cut off the response becasue it was too big. Or the Jsoup User-Agent string made the webserver respond with different content.

Comment: Correction, the input file and the contents from the get method is not entirely the same. The input file is the complete webpage that I downloaded for testing. Does my code snippet with Jsoup.connect().get() look accurate?

Comment: Thanks to the comments, upon further inspection of the two htmls the problem lies in the url being redirected because there was no authentication.